# Associate Key-Value pair with textBox autoComplete extender

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

How do I associate a Key-Value pair with textBox autoComplete extender in a way similar to a dropdownlist?
It is preferred that value will not be visible to user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a great article on the subject http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/autosuggestextender.aspx

I've also written a follow-up article explaining how to call an asynchronous server side auto post back event on a user's selection: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/PostbackAutoCompleteExten.aspx